# Will exporting a function name export all the different function versions in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have multiple functions/dispatches for the same function name. I want to make sure they are all exported. Do I just need to include the name of the function in the export statement and let then Julia do the rest?

Example:

```
function hello(a::Int64, b::Int64)
   #nothing
end

function hello(a::Bool, b::Bool)
   #nothing
end

export hello
```

Will both of these be exported by just doing `export hello`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you export the function name, and that function has two method in this case, and both of them will be available.

And to add, there is no way to export a subset of the methods.

Answer (score 5):

That's right. Actually, there is no version of the `export` statement that would allow you to pick which *method* to export. You export the *function*.

Here is some code which illustrates the behavior:

```
julia> module FooBar
       export foo
       foo(x::Int) = 2
       foo(x::Char) = 'A'
       end
Main.FooBar

julia> foo
ERROR: UndefVarError: foo not defined

julia> @which foo
ERROR: "foo" is not defined in module Main
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] which(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\reflection.jl:1160
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[15]:1

julia> using .FooBar

julia> @which foo
Main.FooBar

julia> methods(foo)
# 2 methods for generic function "foo":
[1] foo(x::Char) in Main.FooBar at REPL[13]:4
[2] foo(x::Int64) in Main.FooBar at REPL[13]:3
```